# How to import/use swift static library/framework in to .mm class extension in Xcode Objective-C Project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

Need to import swift framework classes in c++/.mm class files

Following are the statements declaration in `TargetsDefinedViewController.h` header file

```
    #import<MaterialShowcase/MaterialShowcase.h>

 @interface TargetsDefinedViewController ()<MaterialShowcaseDelegate>
 @end
```

MaterialShowcase is swift project. To use it in Objective-C we have to build framework and then integrate it in Project.
`TargetsDefinedViewController` implementation file extension is .mm

> error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'MaterialShowcaseDelegate'

Answer (score 0):

You can not import swift class file directly in to Objective-C .m file because MaterialShowcase is .swift file and you did first line #import "<"MaterialShowcase/MaterialShowcase.h>". so it's wrong.

You can import #import “APPNAme-Swift.h", Used in .m file of TargetsDefinedViewController and it's working, Try it.

Comment: I used MaterialShowcase as framework.I can able to use it in all view controllers except **.mm** extension classes.

Comment: MaterialShowcase is swift class so you can't import as MaterialShowcase.h file so you can use #import “APPNAme-Swift.h", just try it